Resident Program structure and logic
Using 8086 microprocesor and DOSBox.
This resident program is done with those 2 commands:
TASM.exe program.asm &
TLINK.exe /t program.obj
Why is it not working when I run another .exe which has to be interrupted?
The following code must show minuts and seconds in the screen and update the values once after 1 second aprox (as the resident program is running 18 times per second).
.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
    ORG 100H

PROGRAMA:
    JMP RESIDE
    MINUTOS DB 0d
    SEGUNDOS DB 0d
    FONDO DB 00001111b
    CONTADOR DB 18d

RUTINA PROC
    CLI

    PUSH AX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH SI
    PUSH ES

    MOV AX, SEG @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    CMP CONTADOR, 0b
    JNE FIN
 
    CMP SEGUNDOS, 60d
    JNE CONTINUE

SISEG60:
    MOV SEGUNDOS, 0d
    INC MINUTOS

CONTINUE:
    MOV AX, 0B800h
    MOV ES, AX

    XOR AX, AX

    ;APLICAMOS ATRIBUTO A LAS 4 CASILLAS
    MOV AH, FONDO

    MOV SI, 3001d

    MOV ES:[SI], AH

    ADD SI, 2d
    MOV ES:[SI], AH

    ADD SI, 4d
    MOV ES:[SI], AH

    ADD SI, 2d
    MOV ES:[SI], AH

    XOR AX,AX
    MOV SI, 3000d

    ;ESCRIBIMOS LOS MINUTOS
    XOR AX,AX
    MOV AL, MINUTOS
    MOV BL, 10d
    DIV BL
    ADD AL, 30h
    MOV ES:[SI], AL

    ADD SI, 2d
    ADD AH, 30h
    MOV ES:[SI], AH


    ;ESCRIBIMOS LOS SEGUNDOS
    XOR AX, AX
    ADD SI, 4d
    MOV AL, SEGUNDOS
    MOV BL, 10d
    DIV BL
    ADD AL, 30h
    MOV ES:[SI], AL

    ADD SI, 2d
    ADD AH, 30h
    MOV ES:[SI], AH

    INC SEGUNDOS
    MOV CONTADOR, 18d

FIN:
    DEC CONTADOR

    POP ES
    POP SI
    POP CX
    POP BX
    POP AX

    STI
    IRET

ENDP

RESIDE:
    MOV DX, offset RUTINA
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV SI, 1Ch
    CLI
    MOV ES:[SI], DX
    MOV ES:[SI+2], CS
    STI
    MOV DX, offset RESIDE
    INT 27h

END PROGRAMA


Not working how?  Does it crash the system?  Does it just stop updating?  What do you see with a debugger setting breakpoints in the memory you've reserved for this program's machine code; does it still run from an interrupt handler?  (Bochs has a good built-in debugger built-in to the emulator so it's fully transparent to the guest; I forget if DOSBox can be compiled with a debugger enabled.)  What does the other program do?  Does it overwrite a lot of memory, or does it take over an interrupt handler without chaining to the previous one?  Does it change video mode?

One thing that stands out is that in RUTINA (the interrupt handler) you clobber DS without saving/restoring it like you did with ES.

MOV SI, 1Ch should be MOV SI, 1Ch*4 since each interrupt vector is 4 bytes. I am surprised the linker accepted MOV AX, SEG @DATA when generating a COM program. I'd replace MOV AX, SEG @DATA MOV DS, AX with PUSH CS POP DS. The generated interrupt will set CS which points to where your COM program was loaded into memory. You just have to copy CS to DS since your data and code segment are the same segment.

@MichaelPetch You got reason, thank you for teaching me about this.
My profesor couldn't tell me why my code was not working.


Why is it not working when I run another .exe which has to be interrupted?

With mov si, 1Ch you weren't setting the vector for int 1Ch but rather the vector for int 07h (a reserved interrupt). Every interrupt vector occupies 4 bytes, so the correct instruction is mov si, 1Ch * 4.
You can simplify the chore a bit because there is a DOS function that can set an interrupt vector for you. The reside part then becomes:
reside:
  mov  dx, OFFSET rutina
  mov  ax, 251Ch
  int  21h                   ; DOS.SetInterruptVector
  mov  dx, OFFSET reside
  int  27h                   ; DOS.TerminateAndStayResidient

Another reason why it would stop working is that you allow modifying the DS segment register by the handler. The program that got interrupted will not have expected this!
If the number of memory accesses that depend on DS is small, then one could opt to use a cs: segment override prefix instead of setting up DS which will require 4 bytes (push ds push cs pop ds ... pop ds).
Some more info about your handler.

When your handler begins executing, the interrupt flag (IF) has already been reset by the CPU. Your cli instruction is superfluous.
When your handler ends, the iret instruction will restore the interrupt flag to what it was when the interrupt was triggered. Your sti is not useful.
Your handler (currently) does not use the CX register, so it is not required/useful to preserve that register on the stack. DS on the other hand ...


A quick review
Your "ESCRIBIMOS LOS MINUTOS" and "ESCRIBIMOS LOS SEGUNDOS" are very similar. These are excellent candidates for a subroutine so as to avoid repeating yourself. See DRY.
I would also absorb the "APLICAMOS ATRIBUTO A LAS 4 CASILLAS" in the subroutine:
RUTINA PROC
  push ax
  push bx
  push si
  push ds
  push es

  push cs
  pop  ds

  ...

CONTINUE:
  mov  ax, 0B800h
  mov  es, ax
  mov  al, MINUTOS
  mov  si, 3000
  call ESCRIBIMOS
  mov  al, SEGUNDOS
  mov  si, 3006
  call ESCRIBIMOS
  inc  SEGUNDOS
  mov  CONTADOR, 18
FIN:
  dec  CONTADOR

  pop  es
  pop  ds
  pop  si
  pop  bx
  pop  ax
  iret
; ------------------
; IN (al,es:si)
ESCRIBIMOS:
  cbw               ; Clears AH because AL is positive [0,59]
  mov  bl, 10
  div  bl
  add  ax, 3030h    ; Make ASCII both digits at once
  mov  bh, FONDO    ; Attribute
  mov  bl, al       ; AL is tens digit
  mov  es:[si], bx
  mov  bl, ah       ; AH is ones digit
  mov  es:[si+2], bx
  ret
; ------------------
ENDP


I was doing a clock.. How do I don't repeat myself? Could you be more specific? Also this is my second program on 8086 assembler. Edit: I'm sorry I just saw that you replied with code changed. I see your point now. Either way thank you soo much!
